# Get all items of a sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, directory, subdirectory, sharepoint-clientobject

i want to download all files of my sharepoint list.
I download the files with this method:

```
  public void DownloadFilesOfSpecialtys( )
       {


           using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
           {

               foreach (var item in ids)
               {

                   int listItemId = int.Parse(item.ToString());
                   statics.files = int.Parse(ids.Count.ToString());

                   var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listtitle);
                   var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
                   clientContext.Load(list);
                   clientContext.Load(listItem, i => i.File);
                   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                   var fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
                   var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
                   var fileName = Path.Combine(@path , (string)listItem.File.Name);



                   using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
                   {
                       fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                   }


               }


           }

       }
```

Now my Problem is, that the files in the sub folders arent downloaded with this methode.
Is there an opportunityto go through all sub folders in my list and download all files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your goal is:

> to download **all files** of my SharePoint list

the following example demonstrates how to accomplish it:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     var qry = new CamlQuery();
     qry.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" +
                              "<Query>" + 
                                  "<Where>" + 
                                        "<Eq>" + 
                                             "<FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />" + 
                                             "<Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>" + 
                                        "</Eq>" + 
                                 "</Where>" + 
                               "</Query>" + 
                            "</View>"; 

    var sourceList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(sourceListTitle);
    var items = sourceList.GetItems(qry);
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        //1. ensure target directory exists
        var curPath = targetPath + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((string)item["FileRef"]);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(curPath);
        //2. download a file
        DownloadAFile(item, curPath);   
     }
 }
```

where

```
    private static void DownloadAFile(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item,string targetPath)
    {
        var ctx = (ClientContext)item.Context;
        var fileRef = (string)item["FileRef"];
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileRef);
        var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileRef);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

> Note: compatible with SharePoint 2010/2013 CSOM API
>
> As a bonus, the folder structure will be preserved once files are
>   downloaded

Answer (score 0):

When you have your listItem object, it might already be a folder, so you can treat it as a folder by using the .Folder property:

```
var listItemAsFolder = listItem.Folder;
if (listItemAsFolder != null) {
  // here you can access listItemAsFolder.Files to get all files in the folder
  // also, you can access listItemAsFolder.SubFolders to get all subfolders.
}
```

Btw, there's also a way back: WHen you have an SPFolder object, use .Item to treat it as a ListItem.

Comment: listItemAsFolder.SubFolder does not exist in my case

Comment: it's SubFolders (with s), which is a collection of all subfolders of the folder

Comment: Yeah Subfolders i write it false sry, is no availible

Comment: As any other objects, you have to load them in context first: var folders = listItemAsFolder.SubFolders; clientContext.Load(folders);

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh,  there is no need to check for a object type at all,  you just need to construct the proper query. Besides ListItem.Folder property is only available in **2013** CSOM API